# Spark pipeline error gradient boosting model

Tags: python, pyspark, predict

I am getting an error when use gradient boosting model in python. I previously normalized the data, used VectorAssemble to transform, and indexed the columns, error occurs when when I run this:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
#pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[gbt])
stages = []

stages += [gbt]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)  
model = pipeline.fit(df_train)
prediction = model.transform(df_train)
prediction.printSchema()
```

this is the error:

```
command-3539065191562733> in <module>()
      6 
      7 pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
----> 8 model = pipeline.fit(df_train)
      9 prediction = model.transform(df_train)
     10 prediction.printSchema()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    107                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    108                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 109                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    110                     transformers.append(model)
    111                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 295         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    296         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    297         return self._copyValues(model)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    290         """
    291         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 292         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(
```

What is wrong? I have worked on this for a while but am not sure what is wrong with the data or the code

Comment: can you post how you defined your gbt ?

Comment: from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
gbt = GBTClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features_norm", maxIter=10)

Comment: which version of spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried out with a dummy data, with no test split whatsoever:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline,PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,OneHotEncoderEstimator
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a',7,2,0),('b',3,4,1),('c',5,6,0),('d',7,8,1),('a',9,10,0),('a',11,12,1),('g',13,14,0)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','label'])
str_indxr = StringIndexer(inputCol='col1', outputCol="col1_indexed")
ohe = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=['col1_indexed'],outputCols=['col1_ohe'])
vec_assmblr = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['col1_ohe','col2','col3'],outputCol='features_norm')
gbt = GBTClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features_norm", maxIter=10)
pip_line = Pipeline(stages=[str_indxr,ohe,vec_assmblr,gbt])
pip_line_fit = pip_line.fit(tst)
#%%
df_tran = pip_line_fit.transform(tst)
```

This works. So i could think of two things:

1. The spark version. I use 2.4.0. Is yours greater than or equal to
   this?
2. For the other stages such as minmax scaler or vec assembler, did you
   import it from mlib? This mixing of ml and mlib imports causes
   strange issues. mlib will be phased out so import all your functions
   from ml libraries.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you! I altered my code to resemble yours, but I get an error saying "'Data type string of column col1 is not supported.." and so on with the rest of my columns on the pip_line_fit = pip_line.fit(df_train) line of code, what type of data is supported?

Comment: the model cannot understand strings. so you have to either label encode them if they have ordinal relationship, like "high" or "low"  and one hot encode them if they dont have an oridnal relationship. Have updated the answer to include both, check it out. If it helps, please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: I reran it and now have this error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 13 in stage 70.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 13.3 in stage 70.0 (TID 2295, 10.139.64.8, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (struct&lt;WC_Time:double,TimeElapsed:double,Event_Num:double,HomeTeam:double,PointDiff:double,ScoreMargin:double,Foul:double,BLK:double&gt;) =&gt; struct&lt;type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array&lt;int&gt;,values:array&lt;double&gt;&gt;)
The names are my column names

Comment: as a test, did you try the exact code in my answer in your environment? did you get any errors?

Comment: so the error you are getting is something different. To keep the question and answer precise, can you close the question here (preferably upvote and accept-no obligation) and post your error as a new question with full trace of your error?