# add stringindexer and onehotencoder into a pipeline

Tags: python, pyspark, computer-vision

I would like to add stringindexer and onehotencoder such as labels into the pipeline stages. I've done in the following way:

```
pipeline_all = Pipeline(stages=[stringindexer_stages + onehotencoder_stages,stringindexer_label ,assembler, rf])
```

However, python returns me the following error:

```
    stages = [stage.copy(extra) for stage in that.getStages()]

TypeError: copy() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: why stringindexer_stages + onehotencoder_stages and not stringindexer_stages, onehotencoder_stages?

Comment: It neither works

Comment: can you refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761330/spark-pipeline-error-gradient-boosting-model/62777770#62777770 and see if it works